# How do I convert a Java class to an XML file using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, xml-parsing, jackson-dataformat-xml

With Maven I have the jackson "databind" and "dataformat-xml" dependencies alongside JUNIT 4. I have created a simple Java class called "Simple Bean" with two initialised integers. Using an instance of the **XmlMapper** class I tried to write its' method **writeValue** however it throws the exception: "InvalidDefinitionException" with the message "No serializer found for class SimpleBean and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer". I added the serialization annotation but it returns with an incorrectly formatted class name.

```
     public class javaTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamReadException, DatabindException,IOException {
    
        whenJavaSerializedToXmlFile_thenCorrect();  
    }
    
        @Test
        public static void whenJavaSerializedToXmlFile_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       
        xmlMapper.writeValue(new File("simple_bean.xml"), new SimpleBean());
        File file = new File("simple_bean.xml");
        assertNotNull(file);
        }

//@JsonSerialize 
public class SimpleBean {
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 2;
}
```

The error is

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class SimpleBean and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlSerializerProvider.serializeValue(XmlSerializerProvider.java:109)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4569)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3764)
> at javaTest.whenJavaSerializedToXmlFile_thenCorrect(javaTest.java:34)
> at javaTest.main(javaTest.java:26)
> Suppressed: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil.throwAsGenerationException(StaxUtil.java:47)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.close(ToXmlGenerator.java:1290)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.closeOnFailAndThrowAsIOE(ClassUtil.java:497)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4571)
> ... 3 more
> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
> at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1589)
> at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1618)
> at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1444)
> at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.closeCompletely(BaseStreamWriter.java:926)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.close(ToXmlGenerator.java:1285)
> ... 5 more

If I remove annotation symbol next to @JsonSerialize it simply outputs a text file with the data:

```
<SimpleBean/>
```

How do I correctly format the class to XML.

Expected output:

```
<SimpleBean>
<x>1</x>
<y>2</y>
</SimpleBean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simple bean class fields are private try after adding getters and setters for them.